# ng-pattern only numbers in not required input

Tags: angularjs, regex

I've an input text not required and I want to use a ng-pattern for only digits character, but when I submit the form, the input isn't valid. Why?

```
<input type="text" ng-model="price" format="currency" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/">
```

in jsfiddle, insert product without enter a price and submit:

http://jsfiddle.net/2f6qscrp/266/

ps: I cannont change the type of input!

Comment: Do you mean you type a digit and submit, and the error appears?

Comment: No, I have a form with 5 inputs, only one is required (ng-model="productCode"), but when I sumbit the price input has "ng-invalid-pattern" class and I cannot continue.

Comment: Since the regex pattern is fine, the issue is related to the code. If you want help, please post it (any link to a fiddle is also welcome).

Comment: tried this in [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/VMCg2/103/).. it works there

Answer (score 0):

try with `/^[0-9]+$/` + sign is for accepting one or more digits.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps.

```js
var app = angular.module('demo', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

   $scope.price = '';
   $scope.seeResults = function() {
    console.log($scope.price);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.20/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="demo">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
     <form name="form" ng-submit="seeResults()" novalidate role="form">
        Price <span ng-show="form.$submitted && form.price.$error.pattern" style="color: red;">should be an integer</span>
            <input name="price" type="text" ng-model="price" format="currency" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]*$/">      
      <button type="submit" >Submit</button>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: see the jsfiddle I added